# Is css3 -ms-flex available on non MS browsers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am doing some videos from Microsoft Virtual Academy and stumbled upon *-ms-flex* or so called *Flexbox* in *css3*.

I would like to implement a web app on *html5* and *css3* and this *-ms-flex* would help me very much.

Is this available in *webkit* or *fennec* based browsers on mobile devices?
If this can be used, are there any limitations of use?
Also are there any equivalent for those browser if that is not supported?

I found that : [safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/articles/standardcssproperties.html) has *webkit-box* and maybe there are others for the rest of the browsers(Opera, Chrome and Mozilla or Dolphin)

Comment: Check out this [can_i_use table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: That worked, can you provide more links with demos and tutorials for that?

Comment: I would recommend you to visit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for some tutorial. Unfortunately my office is blocking SSL connections again so I can't provide an exact link.

Comment: Convert all this into an answer so that I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, extending from comment:

According to [can_i_use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), You can use flex box on many modern browsers with proper prefix:

- WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari, Android stocked browser, Chrome for Android, iOS Safari) with `-webkit-` prefix;
- Gecko/Fennec browsers (Firefox, Firefox for Android) with `-moz-` prefix;
- Trident browsers (IE 10) with `-ms-` prefix;
- Presto browsers (Opera desktop) without prefix.

You should be able to find some tutorial/example on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), or (as usual) [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&newwindow=1&q=flex+box+tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, was of great help!